# SSD NVME disks not detecting on Ubuntu 18.04 even after change Sata to AHCI mode but works with 20.04 on Dell Tower 5820

Tags: 18.04, dell, ssd, nvme

I'm facing some issue with detecting the SSD nVME disk on Ubuntu 18.04 while installation. But 20.04 works perfectly without any issues.

I have tried with the latest ISO Ubuntu 18.04.5 and BIOS updated to latest. Then changed the SATA to AHCI mode. still this is not detected.

Disk ->  PM981a NVMe SAMSUNG 2048GB
Model -> Dell Precision Tower X-series 5820

Note:- this is not a dual boot. It's a single installation only

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware?  Dell Precision 5820 with PCI NVME SSD UEFI update & SSD firmware update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402254

Comment: BIOS already in latest version. Let me try with nvme_load=YES grub parameter.

Comment: With my Samsung NVMe SSD, I downloaded an ISO and booted it to update firmware. Magician is a Windows only tool. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisit You can see version with nvme from Linux: `sudo apt install nvme-cli` and: `sudo nvme list`

Comment: S4UFNF0NC01090 PM981a NVMe SAMSUNG 2048GB

Comment: It did not copy full link in previous comment. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ I do not see yours under firmware?

Comment: yea this is a new model